# Why does sed not remove my empty lines?

Tags: shell-script, sed

Why does not this sed command remove empty lines?

```
sed -e 's/\r//g' -e '/^{$/d' -e '/^}$/d' -e ':begin;$!N;/^state-text: {[[:space:]]\n/s/\n//;tbegin;P;D' -e "s/'/''/g" -e '/^$/d' <<< $myvar
```

This command all works fine except the last part -e '/^$/d' for removing the empty lines which appears to be doing nothing at all.
Here is a sample of my content:

```
begin dump

Ctrl_ID:100
```

This is the same content viewed with cat -A

```
begin dump$
$
Ctrl_ID:100$
```

Examining the empty line with an Hex editor shows that all it contains is one single char with the hex value

```
0A
```

Which is exactly the same code at the end of each lines.

I don't understand what's going on here.

`^$` should match, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (empty line remove is now at first position):

```
sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/\r//g' -e '/^{$/d' -e '/^}$/d' -e ':begin;$!N;/^state-text: {[[:space:]]\n/s/\n//;tbegin;P;D' -e "s/'/''/g" <<< $myvar
```

---

The part, which is responsible for the not working empty-line-remove is this one:

```
-e ':begin;$!N;/^state-text: {[[:space:]]\n/s/\n//;tbegin;P;D'
```

going deeper...

> D deletes the contents of the patterns space, up to the first newline (or to the end if there is no newline), and starts a new cycle. The latter means that any commands that come after the D in the sed program will not be executed if D itself is executed.

from [here](http://backreference.org/2009/12/23/how-to-match-newlines-in-sed/)

Comment: That, actually works... why? oh WHY?!! my WTF moment has been upgraded to first class now lol.

Comment: Figures... its the only part of the sed command I don't fully understand. Got that one off the web and adapted it for my script.

Comment: Oh wow. This would actually have caused bugs in the future that would have been a head ache to fix. Thank you very much for your help and catching this.